Find two different matrices that share characteristic and minimal polynomial
Theorem: If $A$ is a matrix in Jordan Normal Form:
• The eigenvalues of $A$ are the scalars on the diagonal of $A$.
• The algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ is the number of times $\lambda$ appears in the diagonal.
• The geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is the number of Jordan blocks in $A$ that have $\lambda$ in their diagonal.
• The minimal polynomial of $A$ is $m_A(x)=(x-\lambda _1)^{\alpha _1}...(x-\lambda _p)^{\alpha _p}$, where $\lambda _1,...,\lambda _p$ are the distinct eigenvalues and $\alpha _i$ the size of the largest Jordan block in $A$ that has $\lambda _i$ in its diagonal.

Using the theory of matrices in Jordan Normal Form, find two different matrices with characteristic polynomial $(x-1)^4$ and minimal polynomial $(x-1)^2$.
So far I have:
Consider two matrices in Jordan Normal Form. If both matrices have characteristic polynomial $(x-1)^4$, then clearly both have eigenvalue $1,$ and the algebraic multiplicity of $1$ is $4$ for both matrices.
Also, since both matrices have minimal polynomial $(x-1)^2$, it means that for both matrices, the largest Jordan block containing $1$ is a $2$x$2$ block
However,  notice that one matrix could satisfy that the geometric multiplicity of $1$ is $3,$ while the other matrix could satisfy that the geometric multiplicity of $1$ is $2$.
So we have two matrices in JNF:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
and $$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Is this correct and enough to satisfy what I was asked?

Yes, that works.

The way the problem is stated, all you have to do is find one matrix $A$ with the given properties, and an invertible matrix $B$ such that $B^{-1}AB\ne A$.

@Gerry What does the matrix $B$ have to do with the question being asked?

@Ben, the title asks for two different matrices that share characteristic & minimal polynomials. OP has done that one way, by finding two matrices with different Jordan forms. I'm proposing a different way, where the two matrices, $A$ and $B^{-1}AB$, have the same Jordan form.
